# TypeError with functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to define a function that returns a list without the first and last items in that list.  However, I get this when I run the function: "TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object does not support item deletion".

This is my code so far:

```
def middle(t):
    """returns a copy of a list with the first and last items removed

    list -> list"""
    t = input
    del t[0]
    del t[-1]
    print(t)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you calling your `middle` function?

Comment: not sure what you mean by 'calling'...

Comment: What are you expecting `input` to be?! The function parameter is called `t`.

Comment: the input should be a list

Comment: No, I mean: what object do you expect the name `input` to be referencing when you assign it to `t`? And why would you want to reassign `t`, given that doing so makes it impossible to access the argument to the function?

Answer (score 6):

`t=input` is assigning `t` to the function object `input`.  You can't slice a function.  `t[1:-1]` will return a new list with the first and last items removed.

Answer (score 2):

You should delete the `t = input` line; that's assigning t to the built-in function `input`, which isn't an array and isn't what you want. Once you do that, you can use:

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
middle(l)
```

which will leave `l = [1, 2, 3]`.

However, a better way of doing this is just to say

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = l[1:-1]
```

This leaves l2 as `[1, 2, 3]`, as I assume you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd go with something like

```
themiddlevalues = t[1:-1]
```

This works on any sort of sequence, and doesn't require a function.  It's probably worth learning about python slice notation, as slices are important to numpy, etc.  See http://codingbat.com/doc/python-strings.html, as slices work the same way across strings, lists, etc.